# Pick dynamic union types from subcomponent props in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, union-types

There are two basic React components:

Sub component:

```
type SubComponentProps = {
  subText: string;
} & DynamicProps;

type DynamicProps =
  | {
      prop1?: "one" | "two";
      prop2?: "three" | "four";
    }
  | {
      prop1?: "1" | "2";
      prop2?: never;
    };

function SubComponent({ subText, prop1, prop2 }: SubComponentProps) {
  return <p>{subText}</p>;
}
```

Main component:

```
type MainComponentProps = {
  mainText: string;
} & Pick<SubComponentProps, "prop1" | "prop2">;

function MainComponent({ mainText, prop1, prop2 }: MainComponentProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{mainText}</h1>

      <SubComponent subText="Text" prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} /> // <-- Error here
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want `MainComponent` to "inherit" `DynamicProps` from `SubComponent` so that `prop1` and `prop2` can be passed from the root level first to `MainComponent` and then to `SubComponent`. At the same time, `prop1` and `prop2` still need to be dynamic, which means that if `prop1` is passed as `"one"` or `"two"`, then `prop2` should be available. However, if `prop1` is passed as `"1"` or `"2"`, then `prop2` should not be available. Something like this:

```
<MainComponent mainText="Text" prop1="one" prop2="four" />; // <-- Should be allowed

<MainComponent mainText="Text" prop1="1" prop2="four" />; // <-- Should not be allowed
```

I tried to use `Pick` utility type to pick `prop1` and `prop2` but it doesn't work as expected as I get this error:

```
Type '{ subText: string; prop1: "one" | "two" | "1" | "2" | undefined; prop2: "three" | "four" | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SubComponentProps'.
  Type '{ subText: string; prop1: "one" | "two" | "1" | "2" | undefined; prop2: "three" | "four" | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ prop1?: "1" | "2" | undefined; prop2?: undefined; }'.
    Types of property 'prop1' are incompatible.
      Type '"one" | "two" | "1" | "2" | undefined' is not assignable to type '"1" | "2" | undefined'.
        Type '"one"' is not assignable to type '"1" | "2" | undefined'.
```

I also tried assigning `DynamicProps` directly to `MainComponentProps` but that didn't fix the issue:

```
type MainComponentProps = {
  mainText: string;
} & DynamicProps;
```

Could you advice what is the problem and how to achieve the described behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [conditional type to distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) over your SubComponentProps union

```
type DistributePick<T, U extends keyof T> = T extends any ? Pick<T, U> : never;

type MainComponentProps = {
  mainText: string;
} & DistributePick<SubComponentProps, "prop1" | "prop2">;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgIwMIHsC2YUDsJeABQCcUwBnKAXigG8BYAKCilMQBUIAPYALmeEICWWAOYBuBgF8oAMigAREFgCGaAQGMiJUuPoNQkeYpXrNZSgyYAfGhaZ2wxMAEYA-LwBE2CO6jX3wAHcUdx07e0cAJjcofwALQghvXxiAMxQ4QhDbJglbazpGMKgHElcPJx8-CKzCsJKwKN4cADcIQlC7CR0GPXBoAFklIVQMLzxTcioCpjQhrHYuXlJ+ITFJGSh8dQBrAB54ZHRMHHHHUgAaGPqK5Pd66oA+bvo1bGWoNJQnXkHho7GCGdKDZalBZkIFjwoABySHQ87ZYqOb4wrzwxH3XjQtIZaGSHovN7AKAIJSEFG-LAjY64QFaYHTOzg+acKGw1no0HXLFOTl1SJYnGEPH0XK6ej6aByATLQQIODACBbNR7ViXACqUFZuAAJuRthAQCgUlBWA9gawtVxdeQlFgQFAXJsdrs1VB1eamhBWu0CZKoJTqQCJhEGbZmZClisRDopLJpbKBPLFcq9gcgyc6WRLndkZUrpF3E8Ca8sO9PhEfnMM7SQ2HQRHWVi4QiucisWjW-ySJWYUKRWKGKX3qTCL3A-9M3WpojG4sYS2Me2Ybyu+Ee4L0sLJEA)